# Startup script with LSB headers not working correctly (dependency problem?)

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, startup, lsb

I am creating a startup script for my Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS server.  The script needs to be run after the Rabbit MQ server.  The Rabbit MQ startup script says it provides "rabbitmq-server".  So I put this string in the "Required-Start" list of my startup script headers (see below).  However, after installing my script with update-rc, both the Rabbit MQ script and my script are at the "S20" level, i.e., I don't think the dependency has worked.  My script is also not starting correctly, but does start if I run it manually after bootup.  Any ideas as to what could be wrong?

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: amqp_receive
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network rabbitmq-server
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Script to provide start/stop/status of the amqp_receive program
### END INIT INFO
```

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  22 Aug 17 00:29 S20amqp-receive -> ../init.d/amqp-receive
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  25 Aug 13 18:14 S20rabbitmq-server -> ../init.d/rabbitmq-server
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Apr 16 18:26 S20rsync -> ../init.d/rsync
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  24 Apr 16 18:26 S20screen-cleanup -> ../init.d/screen-cleanup
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  23 Apr 16 18:26 S38open-vm-tools -> ../init.d/open-vm-tools
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  26 Apr 16 18:26 S45landscape-client -> ../init.d/landscape-client
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  19 Apr 16 18:26 S70dns-clean -> ../init.d/dns-clean
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 Apr 16 18:26 S70pppd-dns -> ../init.d/pppd-dns
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21 Apr 16 18:26 S99grub-common -> ../init.d/grub-common
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 Apr 16 18:25 S99ondemand -> ../init.d/ondemand
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 Apr 16 18:25 S99rc.local -> ../init.d/rc.local
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the scripts run in alphabetical order (as you stated above, the problem is that they both start with `S20`) - so `S20amqp-receive` runs before `S20rabbitmq-server`. I'm with you, something has gone wrong while executing `update-rc.d`. Maybe just execute `update-rc.d amqp-receive defaults` again.

Another solution could be to just (manually) rename `S20amqp-receive` to `S21amqp-receive`. Then this script will be executed after the ones starting with `S20`.

**Note:** It would be nicer to try to fix the dependencies.